# Finder hangs hard when accessing some files on NAS via SMB

Tags: finder, performance, smb, nas

I have a new Synology NAS that I'm accessing over SMB3 (AFP is completely disabled on the NAS). When accessing some files on the NAS, Finder, as well as any app that tries to show an Open/Save dialog and some apps that don't, hangs *hard*. Relaunching doesn't work, force quitting all the apps doesn't work. It takes a full reboot without reopening windows to fix the problem.

One fairly reliable way to cause this is to add a large video file on the NAS to VLC's queue. I also saw it when accessing a .sparsebundle disk image on the NAS. And sometimes it happens without either of those.

[Here's a spindump of Finder](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/lannyheidbreder-mc/33231308e32f3114233485a4965fc2da/raw/290f284cec24b199051f0c00718807a9e6aa5f62/Finder_81802.2.spindump.txt) (Raw GitHub Gist; 11 MB) while this is going on. I can't make much of it, except that maybe an awful lot of calls took the entire duration of the sample. But even that might be meaningless for all I know.

Can anyone make heads or tails of this?

Setup details:

- 15″ 2019 MacBookPro15,1
- macOS 10.15.4
- Synology DS1618+ connected to router via both Ethernet ports using Link
  Aggregation
- Router running DD-WRT
- Mac connected to router via ethernet as well.
- Synology set to disallow SMB versions lower than 2. Connection seems to be correctly using SMB3.

Comment: This *might* be related to the Finder large-file-copy bug, which according to the beta release notes will be fixed in the next macOS update.
Please see: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/macos_release_notes/macos_catalina_10_15_5_beta_4_release_notes for more info.
Can you please provide some more detail about your setup? How is everything connected? Did you alter the SMB config on the Syno? Does the transfer speed keep up when network-hammering the NAS using iperf (there is a Syno PKG available)?.

Comment: Hey, thank you! I added more details to the bottom of my question, but this RAID bug really sounds like the culprit. All my Googling had "NAS" or "Synology", I never thought to search for "RAID" instead. I think I'll wait for 10.15.5 general release before I do a whole bunch more debugging. Thanks again!